# Maintain associated objects in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, associations, vuex

I'm new to vue, but I carefully read the docs for vue and vuex as well. But I'm stuck with the following issue. I also do think it's neither that I would not get it done somehow, but I'd like to go for a clean and probaply best practive approach.

The Setup:
- I have some entities
- I have some users
- lets say an entity can belong to multiple users

Now what I want to accomplish is to display a list of all users having those checked which are assigned to the entity.

I have the following vuex store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        users: [],
        entities: []
    },
    getters: {
        USERS: state => state.users,
        ENTITIES: state => state.entities,
        ENTITY: state => id => {
            return state.entities.find(entity => entity.id == id)
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_USERS: (state, payload) => {
            state.users = payload
        },
        SET_ENTITIES: (state, payload) => {
            state.entities = payload
        },
        UPDATE_DEVICE: (state, payload) => {
            state.entities = state.entities.map(entity => {
                if(entity.id === payload.id){
                    return Object.assign({}, entity, payload.data)
                }
                return entity
            })
        }
    },
    actions: {
        GET_USERS: async (context) => {
            let { data } = await Axios.get('/api/v1/users')
            context.commit('SET_USERS', data)
        },
        GET_ENTITIES: async (context) => {
            let { data } = await Axios.get('/api/v1/entities')
            context.commit('SET_ENTITIES', data)
        },
        UPDATE_ENTITY: ({commit}, payload) => {
            Axios.put('/api/v1/entities/' + payload.id + '/', payload.data).then((response) => {
                commit('UPDATE_ENTITY', payload)
            });
        }
    }
})
```

My Entity-Component loads the users from the store within the created hook. The the entity's data is get from the store from the computed property `entity()`. Also the list of all users is served by a computed property `users()`.

```
created(){
   if(!this.$store.getters.USERS.length) this.$store.dispatch('GET_USERS')
},
computed: {
   entity(){
      const entityId = this.$route.params.id
      return this.$store.getters.ENTITY(entityId)
   },
   users(){
      return this.$store.getters.USERS
   }
}
```

Then within the template I show all the users and a checkbox:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(user, i) in users" :key="i">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="user" :id="'user_'+i" :name="'user_'+i" v-model="???" />
      <label :for="'user_'+i">{{user.name}}</label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I also have a second list of all users which belong to the entity within the the same component's template like the following which I'd like to keep in sync with the 'selectable list'. So all users with a checked checkbox should be listed in that list:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="user in entity.users" :key="user.id">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is where I'm stuck at:
should I use a computed property for the device.users with get() and set() and use this as v-model on the checkboxes? I tried that but it hasn't worked because the user object of the all-users list and the objects of the device.users list were not the same objects even if they represent the same user. And at that point I think I'm doing the whole thing way to complex and I'm simply overlooking the common way practiced vue-users would do it.

So long story short: what is the best way to solve this task? 
I think it's a mostly common task.

Thanks for every answer, if more code / details required I of cause will provide them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the structure of entity look? Assuming they have an array 'users', you could calculate the value for the checkbox by providing a basic javascript function that checks if that user's unique ID is in the list for this entity.

In computed make a new property (so you don't recalculate the same array for every element in v-for):

```
userIdsWithEntity() {
  if (!this.entity) return [];  // necessary in case entity hasn't been instantiated yet
  return this.entity.users.map(x => x.id)
}
```

Then provide a simple function to the checkbox value that returns true or false: `:value="userIdsWithEntity.includes(user.id)"`

Instead of v-model (which is :value and @input/@change to update the property provided in :value rolled into one directive, so you might get conflicts with your :value definition), use @change to handle the (un)checking of the checkbox, dispatching an action to vuex to remove/add that user to the entity.

Comment: thx, thats basically a good starting point! How can I now maintain a second list on the same component, containing all the selected users? I will respectively edit my question.

Comment: I further think you mean :checked instead of :value on the ceckbox, right?

Comment: Yeah, it should be :checked. HTML inputs are weird like that ;p

Different question, but probably best to generate that list with `v-for="id in userIdsWithEntity"` and have a getter for user like you have for entity. `user: state => id => state.users.find(user => user.id === id)`.

Comment: and how can I then access the user's name? and how can I accomplish having both lists synced?

Comment: Sync should happen automatically when you update entity. Both lists depend on userIdsWithEntity and thus if your add/remove user function is correctly updating your entity, this property should be updating both lists. Access user.name the same way you access entity.id.

Comment: well, but havin `userIdsWithEntity`as a computed property, it's rather static and the sync won't happen automatically, or am I wrong? Even using getter and setter, `userIdsWithEntity`relies on the entity of the vuex store. Again, this seems all pretty complicated for such a (I assumed) basic task?

Comment: Using vuex means you'll need to do more boilerplate code compared to just keeping the data in your local state, yes. I can't write your add/remove user code for you, that depends on your implementation. Your getter 'entity' should update when you overwrite your entities with the new entities where the user is added/removed from the entity. Reactivity doesn't work well when mutating an object. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html .

Comment: Okay you're right. I'd like to go one step back to your original example: when I check one of the checkboxes, how do I then mutate / update the selectedUserIds? I can / should not since it is computed?

Comment: Since your getter/computed value is calculated from your VueX state, and the only way to mutate VueX state is by dispatching actions that commit a mutation, you would need to dispatch an action to the store to update your entity's list of users. You can trigger this from the change event of your checkbox. Pseudocode: `@change="$store.dispatch('updateEntity', payload)"`

Comment: I had to adapt my api structure slightly to make it more elegant but finally it worked. Thanks for your help!